# Declare Dependency Injection when the constructor takes a paramter

Tags: c#, .net-core, dependency-injection

Learning `DI` in a `.NET 6.0 Core` Console Application:
I have written this:

```
  static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var serviceProvider = new ServiceCollection()
            .AddSingleton<InterfaceOne, ClassOne>()
            .AddSingleton<InterfaceTwo, ClassTwo>()
            .BuildServiceProvider();
        
        var one = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<InterfaceOne>(); // works. Its CTOR has no params.
        var two = serviceProvider.GetRequiredService<InterfaceTwo>(); // does not work. Its CTOR has a param.

        one.JustSayHi();
        //two.SayWhateverMessageIsPassedToYou();
    }
```

`ClassOne` implements `InterfaceOne` and it is super simple, nothing special in `constructor` so I was able to run that one. But then I created `ClassTwo` and `InterfaceTwo` but I don't know now how to pass my parameter to that class. Here is my ClassTwo :

```
public interface InterfaceTwo
{
    void SayWhateverMessageIsPassedToYou();
}

    public class ClassTwo: InterfaceTwo
    {
        private readonly string _sayThisThing;

        public ClassTwo(string sayThisThing)
        {
            _sayThisThing = sayThisThing;
        }

        public void SayWhateverMessageIsPassedToYou()
        {
            Console.WriteLine(_sayThisThing);
        }
    }
```

Comment: This appears to be a design smell. Typically you do not intermix _behaviors_ with _data_ in constructor injection, and if you need to, you fall back to a factory pattern for instantiating the instance. In your case, `sayThisThing` appears to be the latter. How would you expect that data to be provided in your codebase? It should most likely be passed to a method.

Comment: @DavidL Thanks for feedback. OK so is it better if I have a PUBLIC property in my class to let's say set the value of "_sayThisThing" ?  So DI will just create an instance and then once instance created I would say like myInstance.SayThisThing = "Hello" .

Comment: @MidTown This is a very contrived example, but subjectively speaking it would probably make more sense that `SayWhateverMessageIsPassedToYou` take the string as a parameter instead. Otherwise the method depends on external code setting the property prior to being called.

Comment: @Xerillio thanks, OK I will do that then. In my real world project it was a method that was using a file path to write to . So here I thought I would pass the path as CTOR but looks like it is better if I put the path in a config file and read it from there and just pass it as a normal argument to my Write method .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While Brian's answer does a great job at spelling out some options, it skips the option which I would consider best of all, if it's possible: Refactor your code to separate Services from Values.

For example, if the string value might change with the context of your application (e.g. it's provided as a request parameter), then the interface should be changed to take the string value as a method parameter:

```
public interface InterfaceTwo
{
    void SayWhateverMessageIsPassedToYou(string sayThisThing);
}
```

... then your implementation could use its constructor to inject the *services* that it uses. For example, injecting the console would make the class easier to unit test in isolation:

```
public class ClassTwo : InterfaceTwo
{
    TextWriter _output;
    public ClassTwo(TextWriter output)
    {
        _output = output;
    }
    public void SayWhateverMessageIsPassedToYou(string sayThisThing)
    {
        _output.WriteLine(sayThisThing);
    }
}
```

```
var serviceProvider = new ServiceCollection()
    .AddSingleton<InterfaceTwo, ClassTwo>()
    .AddSingleton<TextWriter>(Console.Out)
    .BuildServiceProvider();
```

If the string doesn't change with context, so it doesn't make sense to change the method signature, consider injecting a separate service which acts as the provider of that string for your class to use.

```
public class ClassTwo : InterfaceTwo
{
    TextWriter _output;
    IMessageProvider _messageProvider;
    public ClassTwo(TextWriter output, IMessageProvider messageProvider)
    {
        _output = output;
        _messageProvider = messageProvider;
    }
    public void SayWhateverMessageIsPassedToYou()
    {
        _output.WriteLine(_messageProvider.GetMessage());
    }
}

public interface IMessageProvider
{
    string GetMessage();
}

public record FixedMessageProvider(string Message) : IMessageProvider
{
    public string GetMessage() => Message;
}
```

```
    var serviceProvider = new ServiceCollection()
        .AddSingleton<InterfaceTwo, ClassTwo>()
        .AddSingleton<TextWriter>(Console.Out)
        .AddSingleton<IMessageProvider>(new FixedMessageProvider("Hi"))
        .BuildServiceProvider();
```

This is the pattern used, for example, to get configuration options in ASP.NET Core: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/options?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Answer (score 1):

## Method 1

To most directly answer your question, though I would discourage this approach:

```
var serviceProvider = new ServiceCollection()
    .AddSingleton<InterfaceOne, ClassOne>()
    .AddSingleton<InterfaceTwo, ClassTwo>(sp => new ClassTwo("Hello, World!"))
    .BuildServiceProvider();
```

Here's the answer in full context with a sample console app...
https://github.com/CodeFontana/FoobarConsoleApp

FoobarConsoleUI.csproj

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>net7.0</TargetFramework>
    <ImplicitUsings>enable</ImplicitUsings>
    <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
  </PropertyGroup>

  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting" Version="7.0.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Abstractions" Version="7.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

Program.cs

```
using FoobarConsoleUI;
using FoobarConsoleUI.Interfaces;
using FoobarConsoleUI.Services;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

HostApplicationBuilder builder = Host.CreateApplicationBuilder();

builder.Services.AddTransient<IFooService, FooService>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<IBarService, BarService>(sp =>
{ 
    ILogger<BarService> barLogger = sp.GetRequiredService<ILogger<BarService>>();
    return new BarService(barLogger, "Foobar");
});
builder.Services.AddHostedService<App>();

IHost app = builder.Build();
app.Run();
```

App.cs

```
using FoobarConsoleUI.Interfaces;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace FoobarConsoleUI;

public class App : IHostedService
{
    private readonly IHostApplicationLifetime _hostApplicationLifetime;
    private readonly IConfiguration _config;
    private readonly ILogger<App> _logger;
    private readonly IFooService _fooService;
    private readonly IBarService _barService;

    public App(IHostApplicationLifetime hostApplicationLifetime,
               IConfiguration configuration,
               ILogger<App> logger,
               IFooService fooService,
               IBarService barService)
    {
        _hostApplicationLifetime = hostApplicationLifetime;
        _config = configuration;
        _logger = logger;
        _fooService = fooService;
        _barService = barService;
    }

    public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        _hostApplicationLifetime.ApplicationStarted.Register(async () =>
        {
            try
            {
                await Task.Yield(); // https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/36063
                await Task.Delay(1000); // Additional delay for Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime messages
                Execute();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.LogError(ex, "Unhandled exception!");
            }
            finally
            {
                _hostApplicationLifetime.StopApplication();
            }
        });

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public void Execute()
    {
        _fooService.Foo();
        _barService.Bar();
    }
}
```

IFooService:

```
namespace FoobarConsoleUI.Interfaces;

public interface IFooService
{
    void Foo();
}
```

FooService

```
using FoobarConsoleUI.Interfaces;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace FoobarConsoleUI.Services;

public class FooService : IFooService
{
    private readonly ILogger<FooService> _logger;

    public FooService(ILogger<FooService> logger)
    {
        _logger = logger;
    }

    public void Foo()
    {
        _logger.LogInformation("Foo");
    }
}
```

IBarService:

```
namespace FoobarConsoleUI.Interfaces;

public interface IBarService
{
    void Bar();
}
```

BarService:

```
using FoobarConsoleUI.Interfaces;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace FoobarConsoleUI.Services;

public class BarService : IBarService
{
    private readonly ILogger<BarService> _logger;
    private readonly string _inputText;

    public BarService(ILogger<BarService> logger, 
                      string inputText)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _inputText = inputText;
    }

    public void Bar()
    {
        _logger.LogInformation($"Bar: {_inputText}");
    }
}
```

Output:
[image]

## Method 2

As discussed in the comments, simply don't require the constructor parameter, and use a property instead.  In this approach, the property is passed at runtime before executing your method.

The downside to this approach is a logic error, where you call your SayWhateverMessageIsPassedToYou() before your property is set. So be careful.

I think this approach is straightforward, so I won't provide a code sample.

## Method 3

In the scenario, which you will run into eventually, sometimes you just have to pass a constructor parameter at runtime.  Thus the best approach is to implement a factory class, which would get injected into your DI, and at runtime can instantiate your required class with the proper parameters.  
  
Here's the same program from Method 1, rewritten to use a factory class...

Program.cs

```
using FoobarFactoryConsoleUI;
using FoobarFactoryConsoleUI.Factories;
using FoobarFactoryConsoleUI.Interfaces;
using FoobarFactoryConsoleUI.Services;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

HostApplicationBuilder builder = Host.CreateApplicationBuilder();

builder.Services.AddTransient<IFooService, FooService>();
builder.Services.AddTransient<BarServiceFactory>();
builder.Services.AddHostedService<App>();

IHost app = builder.Build();
app.Run();
```

App.cs

```
using FoobarFactoryConsoleUI.Factories;
using FoobarFactoryConsoleUI.Interfaces;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace FoobarFactoryConsoleUI;
public class App : IHostedService
{
    private readonly IHostApplicationLifetime _hostApplicationLifetime;
    private readonly IConfiguration _config;
    private readonly ILogger<App> _logger;
    private readonly IFooService _fooService;
    private readonly BarServiceFactory _barFactory;

    public App(IHostApplicationLifetime hostApplicationLifetime,
               IConfiguration configuration,
               ILogger<App> logger,
               IFooService fooService,
               BarServiceFactory barFactory)
    {
        _hostApplicationLifetime = hostApplicationLifetime;
        _config = configuration;
        _logger = logger;
        _fooService = fooService;
        _barFactory = barFactory;
    }

    public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        _hostApplicationLifetime.ApplicationStarted.Register(async () =>
        {
            try
            {
                await Task.Yield(); // https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/36063
                await Task.Delay(1000); // Additional delay for Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime messages
                Execute();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                _logger.LogError(ex, "Unhandled exception!");
            }
            finally
            {
                _hostApplicationLifetime.StopApplication();
            }
        });

        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
    {
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    public void Execute()
    {
        _fooService.Foo();
        IBarService barService = _barFactory.CreateInstance("Hello, World!");
        barService.Bar();
    }
}
```

BarServiceFactory.cs

```
using FoobarFactoryConsoleUI.Interfaces;
using FoobarFactoryConsoleUI.Services;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace FoobarFactoryConsoleUI.Factories;

public class BarServiceFactory
{
    private readonly ILoggerFactory _loggerFactory;

    public BarServiceFactory(ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
    {
        _loggerFactory = loggerFactory;
    }

    public IBarService CreateInstance(string inputText)
    {
        ILogger<BarService> _barLogger = _loggerFactory.CreateLogger<BarService>();
        return new BarService(_barLogger, inputText);
    }
}
```

The rest of the code is exactly the same as Method 1 above.